# Return boolean count in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have the given XML file (https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-noID.xml)  and am attempting to do the following:

Return the number (count) of courses that have no lecturers as instructors.

I've tried

```
let $course := doc("courses.xml")//Course
return count($course/Instructors/not(Lecturer))
```

But instead of returning the number 10 it's returning 13.  Because it's basically giving me a count of

> false false false true true true true true true true true true true

Is there an additional check I need to do to limit the true's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test needs to be in a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates).

Try this:

```
let $course := doc("courses.xml")//Course
return count($course/Instructors[not(Lecturer)])
```

Also, if you're truly trying to count courses, your count should actually be:

```
count($course[Instructors[not(Lecturer)]])
```